# how to increase column values by 20 percent using mysql

Tags: mysql

How do i increase the values in a column with percentage increment using MySQL,  for example:

```
ID      price
1       500
2       800
3       450
```

How do i increase the values in price column by 20%  using one sql query (MySQL)?

Answer (score 8):

Simply calculate 20% of actual price:

```
update your_table
set price = price + (price * 20.0 / 100.0)
where id = (some condition)
```

or a shorter way:

```
update your_table
set price = price * 1.2
where id = (some condition)
```

Comment: Even shorter - `price = price*1.2`

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name=column_name*(100+percentage)/100
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to set a WHERE clause when executing your query, you need first to prepend your code with:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

When SQL_SAFE_UPDATES is 1 you are not allowed to perform UPDATE or DELETE commands on a table without specifying key column. This is done basically to save user from accidentally wiping out table data in case she forgets to add WHERE clause
then do the update.
Your query will look like this:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
update your_table
set price = price + (price * 20.0 / 100.0)
```